# How can I reset a Mac's password from Single User Mode?

Tags: macos, terminal, password

My sister bought a used MacBook about 6 months ago and she has lost her password.

Here is the procedure I tried to use to reset the password:

1. Boot into single user mode (press Command-S at power on)
2. Type `fsck -fy`
3. Type `mount -uw /`
4. Type `launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.DirectoryServices.plist`
5. Type `dscl . -passwd /Users/username password`, replacing username with the targeted user and password with the desired password.
6. Reboot

But when I try the step 4, it says `launch_msg(): Socket is not connected`.

I would like to know what command to enter in the single user mode to know what version the Macbook is running and the right command to reset the password. Thank you.

Comment: In your forth step "dscl . passwd /Users/username" is the "passed" the new password? And is the "username" the username found in command "ls /User"?

Comment: I am going to close this to the canonical question that clearly answers this for macOS Catalina - the accepted answer here is outdated and the linked question will be far more useful to most people with this issue. Please raise a question on [meta] if needed to revise this close or migrate answers or lock this post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you mount the file system, you should be able to use `passwd username` and then put in the password twice.

Comment: You recommand those steps :
1. Type `fsck -fy`
2. Type `mount -uw /`
3. Type `passwd username`
Is there a way to know the user name ? I'm not sure if I should enter the space from the main screen name...

Comment: If I remember right I tried that also yesterday and the system was asking me to enter `launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.DirectoryServices.plist` first :(

Comment: You can do an ls /Users/ and view the users list there.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I was typing Is* instead of ls. (*Capital i)

Comment: It's an l so it'd be LS if in all caps

Comment: Thanks for the specification, I will try this at home tonight I hope it works, my sister has a lot of work on this laptop ! I will come back here on monday and give you your reward :)

Comment: Scroll down to see a much better and more thorough answer.

Answer (score 52):

Try loading `com.apple.opendirectoryd.plist` instead.

1. Hold command-S on startup.
2. Run `mount -uw /`. (`fsck -fy` is not necessary.)
3. In 10.7 and later, run:

   ```
    launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.opendirectoryd.plist
   ```

   or in 10.6 and earlier:

   ```
   launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.DirectoryServices.plist
   ```
4. Run `passwd username` and reset the password.
5. Run `reboot`.

A second way to reset the login password of an account is to use Reset Password.app from the recovery partition:

1. Hold command-R on startup.
2. Open Terminal from the Utilities menu.
3. Run `resetpassword`, which opens the Reset Password application.
4. Select the volume and account and reset the password.

A third way is to create a new admin account:

1. Hold command-S on startup.
2. Run `mount -uw /`.
3. Run `rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone`.
4. Run `reboot`.
5. Go through the steps of creating a new account.
6. Reset the password of the old account from the Users & Groups preference pane.

None of these options resets the password of the login keychain.

If FileVault 2 is enabled, you have to enter a password to start up in single user mode, and you can't use Reset Password.app to reset the password of an account.

Comment: Alas none of this worked in my situation. I just keep getting 'launch_msg(): Socket is not connected'.

Comment: Any reason that `com.apple.opendirectoryd.plist` would not exist?

Comment: `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.DirectoryServices.plist` doesn't exist in OSX 10.4 on my Powerbook G4. Just gonna point that out.

Comment: Perfect, thorough answer. Thanks so much for this. Quick question: can you expand on the consequences of the "login keychain" not being reset with this? Thanks!

Comment: The third way worked for me with Snow Leopard Server; the first and second did not.

Answer (score 7):

I kept getting the `launch_msg(): Socket is not connected` message, so I used cd to get to the LaunchDaemons directory and typed in

```
launchctl load com.apple.DirectoryServices.plist 
passwd username
```

This worked.  Not sure why it didn't like the directory path as it had no errors.

Comment: [This answer has already been given.](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/61932/37797)

Comment: The answer was not given because everybody was trying to type in launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.opendirectoryd.plist.  This did not work as I had to go to the LaunchDaemons directory.

Comment: This worked for me too, after I did the following:
  
after you cd into the LaunchDaemons directory at `/System/Library` that you type the command `mount -uw /` in order to make your commands writable

Answer (score 2):

Hold <kbd>⌘-S</kbd> on startup, then type

```
/sbin/fsck -y
/sbin/mount -uw /
sh /etc/rc

passwd [username of account you want to change here]
```

It should ask you to enter the new password twice.

```
reboot
```