# leopard forgot password+launch_msg socket is not connected

Tags: macos, password, leopard

I was working on increasing the speed of an ancient (6 years old) iMac running Leopard when I accidentally set the password incorrectly. I then turned to the internet to look for an answer and found: 
http://www.macyourself.com/2009/08/03/how-to-reset-your-mac-os-x-password-without-an-installer-disc/
Which seemed to work fine until I reached

```
launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.DirectoryServices.plist
```

Which returned the error

```
launch_msg socket is not connected
```

I decided to ignore this and see where this would lead me, when I got to:

```
dscl . -passwd /Users/username password
```

It told me that I had to run:

```
launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.DirectoryServicesLocal.plist
```

which returned the same error.

Additionally the system is very slow despite Activity Monitor telling me no programs are using more then 2% cpu or 50 mb ram. Could this be connected?

It's also worth noting that the disc reader was damaged some time ago and is useless.

Anyone got a fix?

Comment: Since you successfully hacked your own mac, how about making new account.

Comment: I'm a bit hesitant to close this as a duplicate now that you have added a bounty, but http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61905/how-can-i-reset-a-macs-password-from-single-user-mode looks rather similar.

Comment: I tried that but I keep getting the socket error so it's not really the same. (it comes down to the same as the link I followed originally tried it the same but that didn't work).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above worked on osx 10.5.8

I didn't use the "/" in mount -uw and once I did that it let me reset the password

Working command: mount -uw /

Comment: I had forgotten I asked about this here but this does indeed work.

Answer (score -1):

Did you follow the instructions exactly? I had the same problem, until I realized that I had omitted the `/` at the end of `mount -uw /`.

Can't comment on slowness or damaged hardware, that seems unrelated.