# delete admin partition

Tags: partition, install, login, administrator

I’m new to MacOS world.

By accident I deleted the admin partition (Directory). Every time when I want to install a programme, the system ask me for the admin login. I enter the login but it is not accepted.

I tried yesterday to reinstall a new OS via recovery to get everything new.
The reinstallation was successful (it took more than 2 hours ), but as started the system I found that all my data is still there and I still have the same admin login problem and the same username.

I have tried resetpassword via Recovery but I get a window which says there is user account available

my question is:

How can i fix this problem quickly?

Any advice will be apreciated

Comment: There's no "admin" partition; are you referring to a particular folder?  The quickest and easiest way to solve this is to reinstall just as you did before, but prior to doing so, wipe the drive using Disk Utilities (top menu bar of the installer)

Comment: yes my data is still there. i still have a user  to log in but it is not an admin user. i cant install any programm because i will be asked for an admin login which i dont know. how to delete this password.

Comment: Use the `rm .../.AppleSetupDone` work-around: [How can I reset a Mac's password from Single User Mode?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/61932/93229) (use the "third way"!)