# How can I mount the root Data volume as writable on macOS 10.15 Beta 1 when booted into Single User Mode?

Tags: macos, single-user

I need to reset my admin password (https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/61932/17533). Can't boot into Recovery Volume, so I need to boot into Single User Mode and modify the Data volume.

When booting into Single User Mode, the system shows the following help:

```
To mount the root device as read-write:
    $ /bin/mount -X /
```

However, that leads to an error message:

```
mount: illegal option -- X
```

I also tried the old `mount -uw -`, but that leads to some *firmlink* related messages, and afterwards I still have no writeable Data area.

`mount` shows that the Data volume is already mounted at `/System/Volumes/Data` as read-only. Trying to unmount it with `umount` leads to an "Operation not permitted" error.

`mount -uw /dev/disk1s1` (which is the Data partition as shown by `mount`) leads to the error "Found 2 volumes in group ... Failed to stat file //AppleInternal, error No such file or directory".

Comment: Please submit beta feedback about this issue, if you haven't already.

Comment: Have done that, of course. Would have also posted on openradar site if it would accept the new FB numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I remounted the root first with `mount -uw /` followed by `mount -uw /System/Volumes/Data` to remount the data overlay. Be careful not to add a trailing `/` because it'll fail with `"unknown special file or file system" /System/Volumes/Data/`

Both issued a bunch of error messages, but everything was writable after that (as verified by the output of `mount` and also by `touch`ing some files in `/` and `~`.

Comment: You are the man ! I was struggle this for hours, until i saw your answer, I was missing the second command. Thank you Thank you.